# Where should I perform Retrofit operations?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, mvp, dagger-2

I'm new to `MVP`, `Retrofit` and `Dagger`, so I've decided to make a simple app based on Riot Games API, that just shows some game's info in a list. Everything works fine, but it made me wonder: "Is presenter a good place to do such things, like Retrofit operations? I couldn't find anything about it. There are some simple examples how to use Retrofit, but they are sometimes shown even inside an activity class, which doesn't seem right to me.

So, here is my question: Where should I perform such operations to make the code as clean as possible?

My app repository: https://github.com/Mallorax/Rito_Api_Test

Comment: Couldn't find anything? Lots of MVP Retrofit articles in my search results... https://github.com/jeancsanchez/Simple-MVP-Retrofit-example

Comment: I could find a lot about Retrofit that's for sure, but not much about what is a right place to use it.

Comment: Ok here's some stuff to get you moving: [Android Architecture (Google)](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) [Android Architecture Components (Google, MVVM)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/index.html) You can check out my approach - MVP using dagger, rxjava, retrofit and Repository pattern to abstract the networking layer - [here](https://github.com/AndrejJurkin/udacity-popular-movies-mvp-dagger-rxjava).

Answer (score 1):

If the Model is what Retrofit returns, you can't put the call there.

The View is intended to separated from the Presenter, and subscribes via Callback interfaces, which Retrofit provides out of the box.

Therefore, your only option without involving some Service layer is to put Retrofit in the Presenter.

Comment: Well in such a simple app my modell is indeed what Retrofit returns, but in more advanced apps should i use Retrofit in model layer or should i involve service?

Comment: I think you are confusing a Retrofit `Service` interface and I meant a logical code layer between the presenter and the view's callback implementation. The model is only there to store getters and setters, not business logic

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to place some network call to plain class e.g. Interactors for example LoginInteractor which contains loginMethod, than when it finishes pass the result to the presenter class, which will handle the data and will convert (or not) it for some kind of model which is ready to be presented on UI.

- Activity/fragment contains Presenter and Presenter contains Interactor(s)

---